# Yii2 Symfony mailer not working with AWS SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii2, amazon-ses, symfony-mailer

Recently I migrated my application mailer from `Swiftmailer` to `Symfony` due to deprecation notification from Yii.
I use `AWS SES` services to send email through SMTP, which was working perfectly with Swiftmailer but after migration, no mails are received but the function returns `true`.
I followed [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer) method to install the mailer. Sharing my codes for better understanding.

**config/main-local.php**.

```
$password = 'MY_AWS_SES_PASSWORD';
$password = urlencode($password);
'mailer' => [
        'class' => \yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::class,
        'transport' => [
            'scheme' => 'smtps',
            'host' => 'email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
            'username' => 'MY_AWS_SES_USERNAME',
            'password' => $password,
            'port' => '465',
            'dsn' => 'sendmail://default',
        ],
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
    ],
```

Sample Mail Function.

```
    public function actionMail()
{
    return Yii::$app
        ->mailer
        ->compose()
        ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail')
        ->setTo($model->to_email)
        ->setSubject('Account registration at ' . Yii::$app->name)
        ->setTextBody($messages)
        ->send();
}.
```

Can any one help me what I am missing on the configuration?

Comment: Try to enable debug for mailer, is it has anything weird?

Comment: Found the solution using an alternative. problem was due to the DNS issue. Will share the same as my answer, may help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the supports, it was due to the DNS, found the solution, sharing for the future references..

```
$password = 'MY_AWS_SES_SMTP_PWD';
$password = urlencode($password);
    'mailer' => [
            'class' => \yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::class,
            'transport' => [
                'dsn' => 'ses+smtp://MY_AWS_SES_SMTP_USERNAME:' . $password . '@default?region=ap-south-1',
            ],
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
        ],
```

Please make sure you install symfony amazon-mailer using below command.

```
composer require symfony/amazon-mailer.
```

Detailed documentation is available on this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/mailer.html#using-a-3rd-party-transport).